# Laravel 4.2 and Mysql Connection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have Xamp(which runs mysql)  which i always use to run every laravel project i do (laravel 5+) and works fine.

Now, i have a project built with laravel 4.2 which i connected to the Xamp i use. I have been able to migrate and seed the tables. But now, when i try to load the page `localhost:8000`, it get this error

> > SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

After reading for solution online,  i realized the project is not connecting to mysql on the Xampp for some reasons which i don't know.

I have downloaded mysql and when i run the new mysql downloaded, and run `localhost:8000`, it recognizes the new mysql.

How can i solve this issue by making the laravel 4.2 project rely on the mysql on my Xampp?

PS: sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have same DB configuration in both the files in case you're using an environment file.

```
'host'      => 'localhost',
'database'  => 'yourlaraveldb',
'username'  => 'yourdbuser',
'password'  => 'yourdbpass',

> app/config/database.php
> .env
```

With below setup in my Windows 10, it's working fine though.

```
PHP 5.6.30
XAMPP Version 5.6.30
XAMPP Control Panel Version 3.2.2
Laravel 4.2
```